# Append value only when not found

Tags: python

If a taxonomy in taxonomies is not in translations. I want it to print `152W00000X | Not Found` currently all of the lines print with Not Found. if I remove the `else` I get an out of range error.

```
taxonomies = ['152W00000X', '156FX1800X', '200000000X', '261QD0000X', '3336C0003X', '333600000X', '261QD0000X']
translations = {'261QD0000X': 'Clinic/Center   Dental', '3336C0003X': 'Pharmacy        Community/Retail Pharmacy',  '333600000X': 'Pharmacy'}
a = 0
final = []

for nums in taxonomies:
    for i, v in translations.items():
            if nums == i:
                    data = v
                    final.append(data)
            else:
                    final.append('Not Found')

for nums in taxonomies:
    print nums, "|", final[a]
    a = a + 1
```

Current output is:

```
152W00000X | Not Found
156FX1800X | Not Found
200000000X | Not Found
261QD0000X | Not Found
3336C0003X | Not Found
333600000X | Not Found
261QD0000X | Not Found
```

The ideal output is:

```
152W00000X | Not Found
156FX1800X | Not Found
200000000X | Not Found
261QD0000X | Clinic/Center   Dental
3336C0003X | Pharmacy        Community/Retail Pharmacy
333600000X | Pharmacy
261QD0000X | Clinic/Center   Dental
```

---

```
taxonomies = ['152W00000X', '156FX1800X', '200000000X', '261QD0000X', '3336C0003X', '333600000X', '261QD0000X']
translations = {'261QD0000X': 'Clinic/Center   Dental', '3336C0003X': 'Pharmacy        Community/Retail Pharmacy',  '333600000X': 'Pharmacy'}
a = 0
final = []


for nums in taxonomies:
    final.append(translations.get(nums, 'Not Found'))

for nums in taxonomies:
    print nums, "|", final[a]
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: Are there are lots of lines in `IDVtaxo` which don't contain `nums`?

Comment: four lines at the top

Comment: There you go! For each `line` without `nums` it appends `'Not Found'`

Comment: No. When taxonomies only contains nums that exist in IDVtaxo the script works perfectly fine. The issues comes from nums in taxonomies not being in IDVtaxo.

Comment: Try to [reduce your code example to the minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which still doesn't work. Forget about taxonomies. Write new code, with example input and output. You don't even need to use files, just have a multi-line string representing `IDVtaxo`.

Comment: I have simplified the code

Comment: This is great! Rarely do people rise to the challenge so well. Really good.

Comment: I think ive got it figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `re` to split `IDVtaxo.txt` at two or more spaces. Unless the source is actually delimited by tabs then this will work.

```
import re

with open('IDVtaxo.txt') as f:
    idvtaxo = {re.split(r'\s{2,}', x)[0]: re.split(r'\s{2,}', x)[2] for x in f.read().splitlines()}

with open('taxonomies.txt') as f:
    taxonomies = f.read().splitlines()

for taxonomy in taxonomies:
    data = taxonomy.split('|')
    tranlated = idvtaxo.get(data[1], 'Not Found')
    print '%s|%s' % (taxonomy, tranlated)
```

Comment: factaxo = {re.split(r'\s{2,}', x)[0]: re.split(r'\s{2,}', x)[2] for x in f.read().splitlines()}
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ok apparently you are running python3...fixed now